# Python requests "Max retries exceeded with url" error

Tags: python, python-requests

I have virtual server launch process that i need to implement and one of the process requires generated ssh keys in newly launched instances to be added to deployment server "authorized_keys" file.

In order to do it i created a simple flask app that will be listening incoming get requests in deployment server with ip and port number of the instance which its key will be added to the authorized_keys.

Here is the flask app that will be on the deployment server:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
import requests
import os
from time import sleep

app = Flask(__name__)


#Get the ip and port number from the newly launched port
@app.route('/<ip_addr>/<port>')
def get_ip_port(ip_addr, port):

    #rmt_response = requests.get('http://%s:%s/id_rsa.pub' % (ip_addr, port))
    rmt_response = requests.get('http://127.0.1.1:9090/id_rsa.pub', timeout=1)
    #sleep(5)
    if rmt_response.status_code == 200:
        auth_file = open("authorized_keys", "a")
        auth_file.write(rmt_response.content)
        return render_template('layout.html', ip_addr=ip_addr, port=port, \
                           srvrsp=rmt_response.content, rmt_response=rmt_response)
    else:
        return render_template('layout.html', rmt_response=rmt_response)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Here is the python app that will be launched on the new server instances

```
import sys, socket
import BaseHTTPServer
from SimpleHTTPServer import SimpleHTTPRequestHandler
import requests

HandlerClass = SimpleHTTPRequestHandler
ServerClass = BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer
Protocol = "HTTP/1.0"



local_ip = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())

if sys.argv[1:]:
    port = int(sys.argv[1])
else:
   port = 9090

#Send the ip and the port num to deployment host
r = requests.get("http://127.0.0.1:5000/%s/%s"%(local_ip,port))
#For debug only
rtext = "http://127.0.0.1:5000/%s/%s"%(local_ip,port)
server_address=(local_ip, port)

HandlerClass.protocol_version = Protocol
httpd = ServerClass(server_address, HandlerClass)

sa = httpd.socket.getsockname()
print "Serving HTTP on", sa[0], "port", sa[1], "..."
print local_ip
print r
print rtext
httpd.serve_forever()
```

When i run the instace code(above) and issue get requests via browser and also run python requests get i receive the expected result which is the content of the id_rsa.pub file. But when the exact request issued from the Flask app it gives me an error.

```
ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.1.1', port=9090): Max retries exceeded with url: /id_rsa.pub (Caused by <class 'socket.error'>: [Errno 111] Connection refused)
```

I did research this error as it relates to python requests but was not able to find a conclusive solution. I know for fact the file is served since i can download it from browser, i can issue a request

```
x = requests.get("http://127.0.1.1:9090/id_rsa.pub")
```

able to get the content of the file but it does not work within flask app for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

The request in the second script:

```
r = requests.get("http://127.0.0.1:5000/%s/%s"%(local_ip,port))
```

happens before the server starts listening, at the bottom of that script. The flask app meanwhile makes an immediate request back:

```
rmt_response = requests.get('http://127.0.1.1:9090/id_rsa.pub', timeout=1)
```

If the server were already listening and just slow, the timeout parameter would work, but since the server is not listening, the "connection refused" happens immediately. Your flask request raises an exception before your server on 9090 is even listening.

To make this work, you'd have to either introduce a delay in the flask app between receiving the incoming request and making the outbound request, or else set the initiating request to run in a thread after the server starts listening.